# Method to generate keywords out of a scientific text?

Tags: nlp, keyword

Which method of text analysis should I use if I need to get a number of multiword keywords, say (up to) 5 per text, analysing a scientific text of some length? In particular, the text could be

1. a title,
2. or an abstract.

Preferably a method already scripted on Python.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [keyword extraction](https://towardsdatascience.com/keyword-extraction-process-in-python-with-natural-language-processing-nlp-d769a9069d5c), [collocation finding](https://www.nltk.org/howto/collocations.html) or [text summarization](https://medium.com/luisfredgs/automatic-text-summarization-with-machine-learning-an-overview-68ded5717a25). Depending on what you want to use it for you could also look into general [terminology extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminology_extraction). These are just some methods, there are also other approaches like topic modeling etc.

Collocation finding/terminology extraction are more about finding domain-specific terminology and require a larger amount of corpora, but they can help to unify the generated tags. Basically you would first run this kind of analysis to find ngrams which are domain-specific and therefore in scientific literature indicative of the topic and in a second step you would mark the occurence of these extracted ngrams in the original texts.

Keyword extraction and text summarization lean more towards being applied to single texts, but obviously the resulting tags are going to be less unified.

It's difficult to say which method makes the most sense for you as this depends on the amount of data you have, the diversity of topics within the data you have, what you are planning to do with the keywords/tags and how much time you want to spend to optimize this extraction.